# Django Channels on IIS

Tags: python, django, iis, fastcgi, django-channels

I have a Django app deployed on IIS with FastCGI. Now, I have installed Django Channels in it and also Daphne to run WebSockets. Everything is working fine locally, but now I am struggling to understand how to handle Django Channels on IIS. Any ideas?

I have IIS instaled in Window Server 2019 and I implement Redis Layer in sockets how to handle this?

Comment: You might find similar things out there in the last section https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/running-flask-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/

Comment: Integrating Django Channels with IIS on Windows Server can be a bit tricky due to the differences in architecture and how IIS handles requests compared to traditional web servers like Apache or Nginx.